# chartkick how to pass hAxis.format to the underlying library

Tags: charts, ruby-on-rails-4

I know you can use the :library=>{:pointSize=>0} syntax to pass options to the underlying charting library (Google charts in my case).

However, I can't figure out how to set the hAxis.format option. I've tried

```
<%= line_chart(@chart_data, :library=>{:pointSize => 0, :hAxis => "{format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'}"}, :min => @vmin, :max => @vmax) %>
```

and

```
<%= line_chart(@chart_data, :library=>{:pointSize => 0, :hAxis.format => "yyyy-mm-dd"}, :min => @vmin, :max => @vmax) %>
```

Both ways result in errors. What's the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close.

`<%= line_chart @chart_data, :library => {:pointSize => 0, :hAxis => {:format => "yyyy-mm-dd"}, :min => @min, :max => @max} %>`